# Edit several dataframes in loop with column names and adding columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 10 datasets in a folder, with 4 columns, which I wish to read in as seperate dataframes in r, for which I use the following to do:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for(i in 1:length(temp)){
  assign(paste("name",i,sep = ""), as.data.frame(read.table(temp[i])))
}
```

Then if i want to change the column names as well as adding a new column V5 <- V3**2 in either the same loop or a different loop, how could this be done.

The other suggestions for changing column names i've seen here in stackoverflow suggest creating a list of columns and then changing them. But they dont change the data in the global environment.

Could any of you help with this?

Many thanks.

Comment: I discourage the use of `assign` in almost every situation. In this case, I'd suggest the data be in a list, ala `x <- lapply(temp, read.table)`. If you need to add columns, you can do `x <- lapply(x, function(L) transform(L, V5=V3^2))`.

Comment: thanks, could one then also just use lapply to change column names of those file columns?

Comment: Certainly. You can do whatever you want. If you want to change the names in just one of them, then you can do `colnames(x[[3]]) <- c(...)`. If you want to change the second column name in all of them, then `x <- lapply(x, function(L) { colnames(L)[2] <- "quux"; L; })`.

Answer (score 1):

The following will read-in the .csv files in "path" , unifying their column names and adding an additional computational column and then combine them all into a single data fame.

```
path <- ""
temp <- list.files(path=path,pattern="*.csv",full.names = T)
dfs <- lapply(temp,function(x)
  {
    df <- read.csv(x,stringsAsFactors = F,col.names=c("col1","col2","col3","col4"))
    df$col5 <- 1*2
    df
  })

do.call("rbind",dfs)
```

Comment: I think there is a slight blur of concepts here. The OP asked about dealing with multiple frames but never suggested that they be combined, so the `do.call` at the end is presumptuous. (It is certainly valid in many situations, I don't know that it is here.) Good safe use of `full.names`, I always encourage it in a defensive coding posture.

Answer (score 0):

Rename all the datasets in an order like *df-01*, *df-02*... *df-10* and read like following

```
   for(ii in 2:5){
       input_csv <- sprintf('sample_-%02d.csv', ii)
       read.csv(input_csv, stringsAsFactors = F,col.names=c("col1","col2","col3","col4"))
       print(input_csv)
       df$V5 <- df$V3**2
    }
```